# Are questions about other Linux distros acceptable?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is it acceptable to ask elementary questions about Linux that will be of interest to Ubuntu users (e.g., how do I lock the screen in Xfce?) though one may be using another distro? Such questions will probably have similar answers for Ubuntu as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seeing as there is now a [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange site (public beta opens on 17th August) I believe such questions should not be encouraged.

Comment: This sounds reasonable--thanks.

Comment: if it is a question a user of an Ubuntu flavour has, it is absolutely acceptable, even encouraged.

xfce is part of Xubuntu, therefore the question is on-topic. 
If the question is not relevant to Xubuntu, because particular issue would only occur on a non-Ubuntu distro then it would be off-topic.

Comment: I find it humorous that questions about Ubuntu on [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or the [Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange site will likely not be forwarded to Ask Ubuntu since they'd probably be just as on-topic there.

Answer (score 4):

XFCE is an ACCEPTABLE question in my opinion - because Xubuntu (a supported flavor) uses XFCE as it's Window Manager. However As was pointed out, Unix and Linux StackExchange is in private beta and will soon be public - those questions will likely be migrated there.