# Migration Paths?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration

Migration paths allow for questions to be moved from Ask Ubuntu to other sites in the [Stack Exchange network](http://stackexchange.com/sites). The idea is that rather than simply closing questions as being "off-topic", then the questions can be moved to be the correct Q&A website.

These could allow us to keep our site on topic and at the same time not being 'mean' by simply closing questions and effectively preventing the asker from getting answers to valid (but off-topic) questions.

From the [Stack Exchange blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/new-question-migration-paths/):

> If you’d like to make a case that a migration path should be unlocked between two sites — show us examples of those questions being closed as off-topic on the site.

So what migration paths would we like?

Comment: Related topic: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285467/a-proposed-philosophy-of-question-migration

Answer (score 20):

I believe it should be possible to move questions from Ask Ubuntu to the [Unix/Linux site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Examples of questions that have been closed that could have been migrated include:

- [Where can I see Debian Squeeze selected artwork? [closed]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12768/where-can-i-see-debian-squeeze-selected-artwork-closed)
- [Are my packages that outdated that installing one package breaks dependencies and suggests I remove *critical* packages? [closed]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11405/are-my-packages-that-outdated-that-installing-one-package-breaks-dependencies-and)

Additionally, it seems that the general consensus from [this discussion](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/684/linux-mint-and-other-unofficial-derivatives-on-topic) is that we are not warmly welcoming questions on Ubuntu derivatives such as Linux Mint. So far none of these questions have been closed, but I suspect the community would be far happier closing questions about Ubuntu derivatives if they were being sent on to Unix/Linux rather than being simply trashed. Examples include:

- [How do I connect to a wireless network using a TP-Link TL-WN321G USB adapter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11947/how-do-i-connect-to-a-wireless-network-using-a-tp-link-tl-wn321g-usb-adapter)
- [Additional Driver Install fails, says check “/var/log/jockey.log”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14242/additional-driver-install-fails-says-check-var-log-jockey-log)
- [Keryx is closing unexpectedly in Linuxmint 10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15271/keryx-is-closing-unexpectedly-in-linuxmint-10))

*Note: I appreciate there is likely to be less support for migration of questions in the opposite direction, from Unix/Linux SE to Ask Ubuntu, so that isn't part of this proposal.*

Comment: Anyone have an update on this?

Comment: Speaking as a [unix.se] regular and [ubuntu.se] occasional, I think this migration path would make sense, even though [very few such migrations currently happen](http://askubuntu.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats) (less than 1/week!). In the meantime AU moderators are certainly welcome to migrate questions to U&L when their only failure here is that they're about a Linux distribution that isn't an official Ubuntu distribution.

Answer (score 11):

I definitely agree that more migration targets should be provided. There is only one path to [Ask Ubuntu Meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com) currently and we can only ask for migration to different sites by [raising a moderation flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270040/711006) and describe the migration in our own words.

I would like to see the following migration targets available on Ask Ubuntu (probably in the stated order). I am providing examples of closed or manually migrated questions.

- [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)
  *For the questions related only to Unix/Linux distributions different from Ubuntu and its derivatives supported by Canonical.*

  - https://askubuntu.com/questions/818540/printf-commad-not-working-in-solaris
  - https://askubuntu.com/questions/835549/cannot-get-wlan0-up-on-kali-linux
  - https://askubuntu.com/questions/831120/how-to-boot-kali-2016-2-from-live-usb-with-grub-2
  - https://askubuntu.com/questions/830205/unable-to-start-google-chrome-in-linux-mint
  - https://askubuntu.com/questions/829858/recover-data-from-previous-elementary-os-installation-using-live-usb
  - https://askubuntu.com/questions/887738/apt-get-command-not-found-in-kernel-3-8-for-beaglebone
  - https://askubuntu.com/questions/998567/tp-link-t2uh-kali-linux-2017-3-error2
  - https://askubuntu.com/questions/999410/root-password-lost-help
  - [Undoing the damage from upgrading from a testing source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1116330/undoing-the-damage-from-upgrading-from-a-testing-source)
- [Super User](https://superuser.com/)
  *For the questions related to hardware, other OS’es, platform independent applications etc.*

  - https://askubuntu.com/questions/803000/installing-ubuntu-with-secure-boot-on-and-no-way-to-disable-it
  - [Choose OS from BIOS menu, NOT GRUB, 2 EFIs 3 Disks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/833581/choose-os-from-bios-menu-not-grub-2-efis-3-disks)
  - [How to run a .exe from MSDN to download the software-fix from Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53072/how-to-run-a-exe-from-msdn-to-download-the-software-fix-from-wine?rq=1)
  - [How can i register a domain name without an online host?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/884307/how-can-i-register-a-domain-name-without-an-online-host)
  - https://askubuntu.com/questions/887740/cant-shrink-c-drive-in-disk-management-more-than-60gb
  - https://askubuntu.com/questions/974184/second-wifi-router-cannot-connect-to-internet
  - https://askubuntu.com/questions/991774/not-able-to-install-windows-10-over-ubuntu-16-4
  - [Hyper threading is not working on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1021529/hyper-threading-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04)
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)
  *For evident programming questions (platform independent).*

  - https://askubuntu.com/questions/812417/python-request-py-syntax-error
  - https://askubuntu.com/questions/836364/what-is-difference-between-write-and-fprintf
  - https://askubuntu.com/questions/860820/i-use-c-to-parse-json-file-but-meet-error-segment-error-core-dumped
  - https://askubuntu.com/questions/915358/how-to-take-arrow-key-input-in-a-c-program
  - https://askubuntu.com/questions/994166/importerror-cannot-import-name-x
  - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028279/cannot-create-a-class-with-attributes-with-default-value
  - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036460/passing-buffer-between-java-and-c-using-swig
  - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043470/how-to-check-if-the-output-of-log2a-is-inf
  - [Why will "0.0u 0.0s 0:00.00 0.0% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w" display on screen from cshell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049202/0-0u-0-0s-000-00-0-0-00k-00io-0pf0w-on-screen-from-cshell)
  - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1102805/how-can-i-int-variables-os-system

Comment: I like your three choices. That should cover almost all cases.

Comment: The big question is if these sites want to allow us to just send them whatever questions people feel like sending. We already close too many things erroneously, why include another site in the mess?

Comment: @Seth Anyone (including OP) can just go and ask the question on the other site without much fuss. I like the idea from the linked [meta-meta article](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285467/a-proposed-philosophy-of-question-migration) that migration should be considered a service for the asker (and answerers, and community as well). The listed question which were migrated (after I raised the moderation flag) got meaningful comments and answers on the target sites. The others were just closed without any meaningful answers, despite they are our main goal, aren’t they?

Comment: Having spent a few years now moderating both AU and U&L, I am very much against this idea. I'm afraid the number of times I have seen flags suggesting migration on questions that actually should be migrated is tiny. I am convinced that allowing the community (which consists mainly of users who know _this_ site and not the others) to migrate would be a very bad idea.