# How can I move my own question to another site?

Tags: support

I believe my [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072203/apparmor-mod-php-mysql/) belongs on another Stack Exchange site, such as Super User.  But, there isn't an option to do so, and it's not getting enough views for a moderator to move it. What can I do?

Comment: Why do you want to move it? It is on topic here and you have self answerd, what exactly is wrong with it?

Comment: I feel like it's more of a server question than an Ubuntu question.

Comment: Just copy it then, the editors, AFAIK, are the same on all sites, so you should not even need to edit it.

Comment: "it's not getting enough views for a moderator to move it" Mods might sometimes see things just because they are getting attention, but the only way to be sure a mod will see a post to move it to another site is to flag it for moderator attention and request a migration. However, this is apparently much more of a hassle than you just deleting your own question and asking it anew on the appropriate site

Comment: There's no "minimum views" requirement for moving a question. @Zanna is right: it's pretty simple to just flag your question for moderator attention and ask for it to be moved.

Comment: What the answers said: it is rarely worth asking for a mod to migrate. Simply deleting and reposting is easier, faster and will make sure your question appears as new on the target site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't, what you can do is press edit and copy every thing, then post it on Superuser with a simple paste, formatting and all, in a couple of seconds.

Then you can remove the question from here.

Answer (score 2):

I've flagged question to be moved to another Stack Exchange site several times by clicking the flag link under the question and flagging the question to be migrated. This action requires approval by a moderator from the destination site. Even though this hurdle exists the question migration was usually successful, and the accept vote and all the upvotes were transferred to the new site along with all the accumulated reputation when the question was migrated.

Comment: However, there are still not many [destination sites available for Ask Ubuntu](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/724/migration-paths).

Comment: It's possible to custom flag questions for migration to other sites too.

Comment: Yes but aren’t these flags handled differently, i.e. by a moderator of the origin site? Moreover, [Meta.SE] says that a [question gets migrated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/217657) after getting enough close votes, moderators of the destination site are not involved.

Comment: Custom flagging is usually handled by moderators twice, once on the source site and then again on the destination site. The person who flagged can select the destination site. Otherwise the migration will often fail because the default migration settings try to migrate the question to the wrong site. For this reason I almost always use a custom flag to migrate questions. I know some of the moderators on the sites that I migrate questions to. Sometimes I ask the moderator on the target site if the question would be acceptable (i.e. on topic) there before I flag to migrate it.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the question, copy all to a new question in the other Stack Exchange site, and deleted the "moved" question.