# What are the 'migration quality requirements'?

Tags: discussion

Recently, I'd suggested a [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1179801/deleted-ubuntu-from-dual-boot-system-now-cant-boot-into-windows) be migrated. It was denied because the post failed to meet 'migration quality requirements'. Where are those defined?  I have read https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/22/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/ which does not seem to spell out much beyond *Don’t migrate poorly-asked or non-constructive questions*.

Comment: Please provide a link to the post. Doing so may help others understand the reason for denial a but. Thanks.

Comment: Related: [What is migration and how does it work? @ Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### TL;DR: Don't send bad questions to other sites.

That's about it. Each site has its own rules, its own preferences, and its own standards. It's important that any question you send to that site meets all of those requirements. If you don't know, won't fix, or don't care about that other site, **don't migrate the question**. Anything else is tantamount vandalism.

Take the following example.

> #### I hate Mint
>
> I installed it because a friend told me to but it's awful. lol.

That is off-topic here, so that means it's on-topic on U&L or Superuser, right? Would you migrate it? That is obviously a flagrant example, but you do occasionally see people forgetting this and trying to migrate some really awful posts.

The threshold for a bad question waivers from person to person, site to site. There isn't a checklist of things I can say will definitely mean a question is accepted. Most people reserve them for objectively good questions in favour of just closing as off-topic and suggesting another site. Migrations are fairly rare.

Comment: Also keep in mind from moderator to moderator the 'requirements' also vary - what one moderator thinks is migration-worthy others may think are not, and vice versa.  (We usually err on the side of caution though and *don't* migrate things)

Comment: Absolutely! I believe —for example— that migrations are an extremely blunt tool and don't migrate the user, which is often what needs to happen in Q&A style events. My bar is pretty high.

Comment: "That is off-topic here, so that means it's on-topic on U&L or Superuser, right?" Do people really believe this? If so, we should simply remove the migrate function for ordinary users.

Comment: What if the OP asks for their question to be migrated? Can mods not accept it? :)

Comment: @Mast Migration is effectively not available for ordinary users on AU currently, see https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/724/migration-paths. According to my experience, it’s more efficient to ask OP to repost their question on the target site than ask a moderator to migrate it.

Comment: @Shayan Often enough the target site will close the question. When that happens, the migration is rejected. The result can be messy.

Comment: @Shayan OP can request but we're still not going to migrate bad questions. I'd like to think we point that out in a rejection.