# Can I ask questions on Linux Mint on this forum

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linux Mint (and other unofficial derivatives) - on topic?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/684/linux-mint-and-other-unofficial-derivatives-on-topic)

Can I post questions on [Linux Mint](http://www.linuxmint.com/about.php) in this forum? Linux Mint is a spinoff based on Debian & Ubuntu, so is it appropriate to ask questions based on the Mint OS here.

I've seen many of my questions closed because they were off-topic.So can anyone tell me whether Linux Mint queries are on topic in this forum?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems like it belongs on meta.