# Should I ask my question on Ask Ubuntu, on Unix & Linux or on both?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions

Let's say I have a question which concerns all Ubuntu users, but not only them. (e.g. about `apt` and `aptitude`). On which Stack Exchange site should I ask it, depending on if my distribution is Ubuntu or if it is ascending (Debian) or descending (e.g. Mint) from Ubuntu? [Here](http://askubuntu.com), on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) or on both?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Ubuntu or one of the other [official flavors](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), you can ask your question on Ask Ubuntu, although you can also ask it on Unix & Linux - your choice. I would suggest looking for questions similar to the one you want to ask on both sites to reach a decision as to where you're most likely to get the kind of answers you want.

If you are using a different Linux distribution, whether it's Debian, Linux Mint or anything else, you should ask on U&L (or even on Superuser)

Posting the same question on multiple Stack Exchange sites (cross-posting) is discouraged. But if you ask a question on one site and it stays unanswered for a while, you'll probably get away with asking it again on another one, especially if you delete the original.

Comment: the problem with that, is that as confirmed in the post linked by Muru, Ask Ubuntu gets much more visibility than Unix & Linux, which is not even specialized in debian derivatives. In addition, in my example, i'm quite sure, that the fact that my distribution is debian or mint, would have no impact on the answer.

Comment: @Camion see https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5877/why-are-questions-about-specifically-ubuntu-based-distros-off-limits and various others

Comment: @Camion  [linux.se] might not be specialized on Debian derivatives, but there is very, very deep knowledge of Debian in the U&L community. We have at least one Debian developer who's a site regular and many of the site's users know Debian very well.  And AU does not get "much more visibility". AU is [the 3rd site by traffic](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) on the SE network and U&L is the 5th, that isn't a huge difference.