# Ubuntu Bitnami stack. Another 'is this supported?' question

Tags: discussion, scope

Relating to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682878/more-than-one-ssl-certificate-in-a-virtual-host) can Bitnami be considered on-topic?

I flagged to close as off-topic, but think I might have been a bit too hasty. The answers about ssl certificates and virtual hosts is useful within Ubuntu installations as a whole. I know that httpd.conf can be used, but isn't created by default on regular Ubuntu installations.

I'm in two minds, I feel like a question that may end up with answers that don't point to apache configuration through `/etc/apache2/` could be misleading.

I've looked at [this](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5821/how-specific-about-not-supporting-non-ubuntu-oss-is-askubuntu) and the other dupe/similar suggestions which lead on from it, but there's still a nagging suspicion that I'm being harsh.

Edit: Then after writing this I had a sudden feeling of self-assuredness and down voted the question, before reading the OPs edit. Now I feel like a jerk again! MUST PUT COFFEE DOWN!

Comment: What does that question have to do with the cloud-hosting whatsit, Bitnami?

Comment: @Oli the question states that it's Ubuntu run on a Bitnami stack, which is different from a default installation, but I was thinking that the question itself is about SSL certs and virtual hosts, so probably OK. I may have just answered my own question in this comment. That question isn't about the cloud hosting platform, but about a specific configuration of Ubuntu... so it's on-topic? I'll close this meta question if so.

Comment: So I see. It wasn't like that when I'd first opened it.

Comment: I'm now in 3 minds, if possible @Oli !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answered it rather than do anything else because:

- Apache is a core application in Ubuntu.
- We have loads of configuration questions about Apache.
- It's something I could answer. I feel that's more beneficial to everybody than shunting it to somewhere else for somebody else to answer.

When I opened the question and started answering it, it didn't mention  Bitnami but even now it does, Apache is still a core app in Ubuntu, we still deal with a whole ton of Apache problems and it's still something I could be helpful on.

I'll freely admit it's a bit greyer than it would have been without the Bitnami stuff but ultimately I see nothing to suggest that it's anything but a change in location of configuration files. It's still Ubuntu and Apache.