# Can questions related to Linux Mint asked here?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linux Mint (and other unofficial derivatives) - on topic?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/684/linux-mint-and-other-unofficial-derivatives-on-topic)

I am terribly sorry for the newbie question ,but since Linux Mint is ubuntu based I.suppose this place is also dedicated to discussion related to Mint. Am I right?

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/faq

Comment: Ask it on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so.  Though Linux Mint is based on Ubuntu, it is popular enough (see [the home page](http://www.linuxmint.com/about.php)) that it is the fourth most popular operating system.  Thus, it should probably be considered separate from Ubuntu.  In addition, Linux Mint is not maintained or supported by Canonical and thus probably does not belong here.

This question also might be better suited to [meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/), but regardless it is an interesting thought.  Maybe it should be a meta community discussion?

Comment: lol ok didn't see the comments before I posted XD