# How far a fork distributions is on topic on Ask-Ubuntu? (is this question on-topic?)

Tags: discussion, scope, migration

I was trying to [answer this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/327905/169736), but as you may notice, it has serious issues that made you think is off-topic:

- It could be a bug/limitation of samba/CIFS.
- The asker is using a "heavily" modified fork of Ubuntu, which could have modified how the kernel and programs works.
- It could be a misconfiguration (highly unlikely since that was ruled out)
- After some edits the asker ask clarifies that he doesn't have problems with what he's doing (he says it works as expected, *while I still believe that his approach is obsolete and don't want to use other methods at all*), but wants to do something that is not approachable within the scope of only Ubuntu, but all Linux distributions (I still am curious about if that is even possible at all).

So, how to deal with this kind of questions? I'm rather inclined to pass them to [unix.se] since, as it is, is not longer within the scope of (only) Ubuntu.

Comment: Hasnt this already been covered? http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/684/linux-mint-and-other-unofficial-derivatives-on-topic

Comment: I swear that post should be in the FAQ. I even used google and didn't found it.

Comment: It is in the FAQ,  all none official Ubuntu derivatives are (with few exceptions)  **off-topic**.