# There isn't a more responsable moderator on AskUbuntu? Just Mitch?

Tags: discussion

Tried to solve a problem I had with my Ubuntu based OS and Wine, but Mitch pretending is some sort of god decided to put it on hold and close it after I hurt his feelings, maybe.

This problem is even more Ubuntu related because it's targeting the Ubuntu forum. Mitch is the only moderator over here? Or I could have the chance to ask my questions when he goes to bathroom and someone else to see it without closing it?

Hope to get a response from the community. Assuming that Mitch doesn't see it first, to close it.

Comment: What? How could you say such thing to someone who has been helping people without getting anything in return for so so many days....if he has done anything there must be a reason (and yes, Mitch was right)..[Read this](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) and don't blame someone without doing the homeworks..

Comment: "but Mitch pretending is some sort of god". Pretending? He IS a God :=D

Comment: Ok everyone. I understand that Mich is not pretending to be God, it actually is.
I understant that I'm a jerk that lowers the community standards and shouldn't be here.
I understand that I need to be an expert in the first place to know all the stuff/rules happening here. And that's the whole point. If I were an experet I would have solved my problem without bothering anyone. But hey, thanks for the nice words and may this be my last topic on UbuntuForums. I don't see an option to close this one and voted for the deletion.

Comment: Sorry but you post a -comment- as an answer. "and may this be my last topic on UbuntuForums." We are not Ubuntu forums. Please do put some effort in the things you do. I see you make mistake after mistake. " I understand that I need to be an expert in the first place to know all the stuff/rules happening here" No you need to do the tour: http://askubuntu.com/tour The site has strict rules for a reason: questions and answer need to stand against time. Otherwise the site has zero value.

Comment: I don't think you have read http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic yet..if you did, you would understand that Mitch was right the whole time..

Comment: A moderator editing a submission that is against the rules is not a personal attack against you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux Mint (and other unofficial derivatives) - on topic?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/684/linux-mint-and-other-unofficial-derivatives-on-topic)

Answer (score 16):

Posting a question on ask ubuntu where this does not deserves to be makes you abusing the system. This should be on https://meta.askubuntu.com/ Besides that: You claim Mitch closed something and do not even include the topic it is about? Making me wast time searching for it?

Advice: If you have a complaint ... make sure you do it correctly, use proper clean English and make darn sure you are correct. Or you will get shot down ...

---

So it is this one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/599269/really-need-adobe-digital-editions-how-do-i-make-it-work ?

Regarding the topic: Elemenetary OS is NOT an official Ubuntu release so your question  IS off topic. We are the official support site for official Ubuntu. If you want support for someone who copied Ubuntu to something random you need to follow the support tools that that OS provides. We can not be asked to know about every change those people made to that specific system.

This site is free of charge but we all need to follow the rules. You probably never read: https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic Please do before you use Ask Ubuntu. It clearly states how this site works and that there is a strict moderation.

My option: **Mitch was 100% correct.** And he EVEN posted a link for you. So he went the extra mile (as I know him to do).

Sorry but you are the one that is acting wrongly in more then one way. You chose Elementary. They decided these are the support options http://elementary.io/answers/no-forum-is-nuts-1 Blame them for not even having a forum. Blame yourself for picking E OS ;)

Comment: If Mitch is a god what does that make Oli and Foss?

Comment: His parents :=)

Answer (score 3):

Submit this question to the meta discussion site and explain why you think your question didn't deserve to be closed in light of the Stack Exchange guidelines.

Answer (score 3):

Let's Look at your post from a wider perspective:

This site is run by volunteers, spending their time to ask and answer questions. The ones who are no doubt the most committed are the moderators. They voluntarily spend *a lot* of time, for free, and play a major role to canalize the huge daily amount of posts.

We learned to know them as people of high integrity. They are doing their job helpfully, professionally and mostly silently. If you think something went wrong, you can always ask, or post a question on Meta. If your arguments are correct, you will be answered accordingly. That actually is the proof of their quality and integrity. They should be admired for what they do.

---

Then a post like yours passes by. Obviously you even don't know where you are (*not* the Ubuntu forums) and you didn't put *any* effort in finding out what is the basic principle of AU. Yet you start rambling, and attacking one of the people we respect for good reasons, in an arrogant and a personal way.

What do you think will happen?

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

I think it needs highlighting that we aren't every other Linux support site and we aren't just another Stack Exchange site. We have a [specific focus](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) and have particular ways of doing stuff, processes that have been refined over many years **to benefit our *entire* community**.

It would be absurd to expect every newcomer to understand our expectations, but we do everything we can to document both the rules and our actions when we uphold those rules. Indeed the close message you received was littered with suggestions for what to do next and another user explained exactly why it was being closed.

I sympathise that this might feel frustrating, but again, we aren't here to service you, we're trying to do the best job for the entire Ubuntu community and through that aim, we have found the need to limit our [scope](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/scope).

I hope you can attain some solace through understanding *what* we are.
We'll be ready and waiting for you when you decide to switch to Ubuntu ;)

Answer (score 1):

> But hey, thanks for the nice words and may this be my last topic on UbuntuForums.

Do you think treating people like you just did is beneficial to solving your problems? Do you think you have a right to insult everyone and leave when you think *you* are done? Do you think you will meet an entirely new set of people for a different problem tomorrow? At some point you will realize that there are limits (not enough volunteers in this world, not enough operating systems, not enough Q&A sites).

This whole thing could have worked out way better if you asked nicely: *"Where should I post my question, if not here?"* One of our moderators could have migrated your question to the sister site https://unix.stackexchange.com/ where it could have been answered. Guess who is around there? Almost everyone of us and a lot more people of this network which you confuse with a forum only for Ubuntu, though the concept of different sites on this network is already familiar to you[?]. Everyone gets points and is happy.

Is being nice that hard?

Answer (score 0):

First thing, there are [more than one moderator(s) here:](http://meta.askubuntu.com/users?tab=moderators)
[image]

The reason your question was closed is that elementary OS is off-topic as although it is based on Ubuntu, it has been modified to make it a different [derivative](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DerivativeTeam/Derivatives#Recognised_Flavors) system (its main feature being the Pantheon desktop) these differences can mean that the problem is due to the modifications done to the Ubuntu base system.

Your issue does appear to be more to do with the wine version you using (if you want help with a problem, please include the version you are using as it makes it easier to answer it). Version 3 [looks like it works in 12.04](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=30159&iTestingId=86850), it suggests looking at the comment [here](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=27978&iTestingId=81595#Comment-85628) (or [here](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=27978&iTestingId=81595#Comment-89409)) for the prerequisites required for it to work are installed.

> 1. new 32-bit WINEPREFIX
> 2. install .NET 3.5 SP1 using 'winetricks -q dotnet35sp1' (make sure you checked .NET appdb entry for hints, e.g. latest winetricks script)
> 3. use 'winetricks -q windowscodecs' to work around bug 33384 (WPF)
> 4. use winecfg and set 'windowscodecsext' component to 'native' (just like 'windowscodecs'

If you are using a old wine version (less than 1.7), it likely will help to install a more recent 'development' version of wine: [How to install and configure Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/q/316025/178596)